# New Ruby on Rails App (not recognizing Gemfile)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 rails new PCMS
  create
  create  README.md
  create  Rakefile
  create  .ruby-version
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
     run  git init from "."
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/snowflake/Documents/TDD/pcms/PCMS/.git/
  create  package.json
  create  app
  create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/javascripts/cable.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
  create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
  create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
  create  app/models/application_record.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
  create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/assets/javascripts/channels
  create  app/assets/javascripts/channels/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  bin/update
  create  bin/yarn
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/cable.yml
  create  config/puma.rb
  create  config/spring.rb
  create  config/storage.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/application_controller_renderer.rb
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/cors.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/master.key
  append  .gitignore
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
  create  public/apple-touch-icon.png
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  tmp
  create  tmp/.keep
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor
  create  vendor/.keep
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/fixtures/files
  create  test/fixtures/files/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  test/system
  create  test/system/.keep
  create  test/application_system_test_case.rb
  create  storage
  create  storage/.keep
  create  tmp/storage
  create  tmp/storage/.keep
  remove  config/initializers/cors.rb
  remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb
     run  bundle install
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 12.3.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
Using i18n 1.0.1
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.2.0
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.7.1
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Using nokogiri 1.8.3
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.2.0
Using rack 2.0.5
Using rack-test 1.0.0
Using actionpack 5.2.0
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
Using actioncable 5.2.0
Using globalid 0.4.1
Using activejob 5.2.0
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mail 2.7.0
Using actionmailer 5.2.0
Using activemodel 5.2.0
Using arel 9.0.0
Using activerecord 5.2.0
Using mimemagic 0.3.2
Using marcel 0.3.2
Using activestorage 5.2.0
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using io-like 0.3.0
Using archive-zip 0.11.0
Using bindex 0.5.0
Using msgpack 1.2.4
Using bootsnap 1.3.0
Using bundler 1.16.2
Using byebug 10.0.2
Using xpath 3.1.0
Using capybara 3.3.1
Using ffi 1.9.25
Using childprocess 0.9.0
Using chromedriver-helper 1.2.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using method_source 0.9.0
Using thor 0.20.0
Using railties 5.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.2.2
Using multi_json 1.13.1
Using jbuilder 2.7.0
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.3
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10
Using ruby_dep 1.5.0
Using listen 3.1.5
Using puma 3.11.4
Using sprockets 3.7.2
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.1
Using rails 5.2.0
Using rubyzip 1.2.1
Using sass-listen 4.0.0
Using sass 3.5.6
Using tilt 2.0.8
Using sass-rails 5.0.7
Using selenium-webdriver 3.13.0
Using spring 2.0.2
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.1.0
Using turbolinks 5.1.1
Using uglifier 4.1.12
Using web-console 3.6.2
Bundle complete! 18 Gemfile dependencies, 78 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
     run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
 ✝  Documents/TDD/pcms  bundle exec spring binstub --all
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
✝  Documents/TDD/pcms   master±  ls
Gemfile README.md app config db log public test vendor
Gemfile.lock Rakefile bin config.ru lib package.json storage tmp
```

Why does my new app not recognize the Gemfile?
Rails 5.2.0
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin17]
Bundler version 1.16.2

Any ideas on how to solve this problem, would be greatly appreciate. Did I miss a step, I'm following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. 
I'm inside the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are yet to `cd` into your project directory. Do this:

```
$ cd PCMS
$ bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ bundle install
$ Bundle update
```